# Building a multistep chatbot with dialogflow using numbers to choose options

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am actually working on a multistep chatbot and I want to make the users choose among options using numbers.

Let me explain:

Step 1: choose option a:
1- options a.1
2- option a.2
3- option a.3
The user can reply with a number: 1, 2 or 3 to pass to the next step

Step 1: choose option b:
1- options b.1
2- option b.2
3- option b.3

And again, the user can reply with one number corresponding to his option b choice.

However, when I do that, the chatbot gets lost between the steps, doesn't recognize the numbers enven if they are in the synonims de the corresponding entities.

Do you have any insight that I can use for that problem?
Thank you in advance